# Connecting a MIDI device with a USB B connector to an iPad

Tags: usb, cables

I'm trying to connect my digital piano (a Yamaha Clavinova CLP-440) to my iPad, to be able to use apps which utilize MIDI input (piano training and such). The iPad only has a Lightning connector input, and the piano only has a USB B female connector labeled "USB to Host". I have a USB B male to USB A male cable, which won't plug into the iPad.

One advice I found is to use a "Lightning to USB camera adapter" from Apple, which is a USB/A female to Lightning adapter. But I can't obtain that quickly, and it's also expensive. Instead, it occurred to me that I might use the regular charging/synchronization cable I have for the iPad, Lightning to USB A male, and then buy a USB A female-to-female adapter, to work like this:

Piano (USB B female) -> USB B male to USB A male cable -> USB A female-to-female adapter -> iPad charging/synchronization cable -> iPad.

Will that work? I'm not sure how the details of USB host/device identification work with respect to using the charging/synchronization cable. Will it allow the iPad to act as a host to the piano? Any other simple solutions I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

As it is a standard charge/sync cable it means that the tablet does not understand to go into host mode.